# Android - FileNotFoundException when opening file with blank characters in the name

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I am building an android application and have the following problem. When I want to open a file from the sdcard using FileInputStream and if the file name contains a blank character, I get the FileNotFoundException. If there are no blank characters, everything works fine. So, if I am to open for example: "My file.ext" it raises an exception, and if the file name is "Myfile.ext" everything is fine.

Any clues on how to resolve that will be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Did my suggestions solve your problem? I am curious, because i was just making a suggestion i am not 100% sure that would work. I would like to know the result so if i run into that problem i will know the solution. Thanks, also accept my solution if it worked! =))))

Comment: Spaces are not "blank characters"

Comment: Yeh, used the wrong word. The thing is, when I look at the sdcard, I see one file "Track 3". Then when I print the path of the file, i get it printed as "Track%203" for some reason. And then obviously, the InputStream does not recognize it as the same. As i said, if I name the file "Track3", the problem is gone.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use an escape character to specific that there is a blank in the file name. I believe it is a '\'...

So it would be like this "my\ textfile.txt"

Answer (score 0):

You could try to let android parse a certain file and open it

```
 File file = new File(Uri.parse(path+"file name.txt"));
 FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Uri should parse your filenames correctly.